# ValueError: Could not find a backend to open `Thumbs.db`` with iomode `ri`

Tags: python, windows

I made a Python script on Ubuntu that takes images reads QR codes using pyzbar and export images in a new folder after renaming it after the data extracted from the QR code. It works well on Linux, but when trying to run it on Windows I get this error:

```
ValueError: Could not find a backend to open `C:\Users\User1\Desktop\QR_read\Images\Thumbs.db`` with iomode `ri`.
```

Here is my folder structure, inside "QR_read":

```
- Python_script.py
- Images_folder
     Saved_images
     img1
     img2 
     img3
     ...
```

Where "Saved_images" contains images that are exported from the code. If this folder already exists when running the code, it is first deleted and then created again.

I did not find any information about this error. Does anyone know where the problem may come from ?